Correct way to get Angular components to update after changes in other components
Been experimenting with Angular 18, and here is my situation. I have a dashboard application containing a left menu component, a header component, and a main window component. I have a toggle button in the header that changes the color of a to-do list item to mark it as done or to re-open the task. In the main window, I have a list of all tasks that have been completed. What is the most elegant way to refresh the main window task list when the toggle button is clicked in the header component?
I have been trying with Signals and Intections and could not get it to work unless I refresh the entire page. I want to refresh the data in my main window table when I click on a button in the header component.

Please rephrase the question and add some code samples with specific descriptions.

https://ngrx.io/docs is the correct way. This will not require any refresh and can detect changes in state and update based on action, effect. You will have to go through a little bit of a learning curve though. I can't suggest any specific way to implement it since the problem statement given above is quite generic. Please explore https://ngrx.io/guide/store/walkthrough

You should look into Subject & BehaviorSubject.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
